# WSO2 Carbon: Re-Theming a single page

Tags: css, wso2

We have followed the guide [provided by WSO2](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/12/retheming-carbon-products) to get access to the CSS / JSP pages.

Our aim is to re-theme / rebrand / restyle the login page. We have found that the login page is part of the jar: `WSO2\repository\components\plugins\org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.ui_4.0.3.jar`
The login page is called login_ajaxprocessor.jsp

The guide mentioned above states the following about JSP's ending with `_ajaxprocessor`.

> By default when create a jsp file ( say “foo.jsp”) in a Carbon UI
>   component, it will inherit header, left menu and footer from the
>   Carbon core UI. But if the file name is “foo_ajaxprocessor.jsp”, there
>   will be no inheritance.
>
> For an example let's consider, “login_ajaxprocessor.jsp” in
>   “org.wso2.carbon.identity.saml.sso.ui” component. It simply omit the
>   header, left menu and footer and display only the content from this
>   file. So we are able to customize this page in to a different look and
>   feel.

Were were successful in modifying the language (buttons, etc) in the JSP files. This Jar also contains a CSS file in: `\web\sso-saml\css\main.css`
We have modified this CSS file to my own style. However, when the page gets loaded, it seems the default WSO2 main.css file is read.

When looking at the default way in which the JSP page refers to the CSS, it says:

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="carbon/sso-saml/css/main.css"/>
```

We would expect that the `/sso-saml/` part wordt select our own modified CSS file.

- Is it possible to configure that for this page only, our modified CSS file will be used? We want to prevent to have to change the default main.css. Also, it is because we want to use specific images, that we want to store in `jar\web\sso-saml\images`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use your custom style pages and apply them. Please refer [1] [2] for more info. This will guide you on your task.
Hope this will help you.

[1] http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2010/11/customize-ui-theming-wso2-carbon-based-products
[2] http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/11/playing-around-carbon-product-themes

Comment: Thanks Manoj, but these guides offer insight in the modification of the entire theme. In this use case, I want to modify a single page, by modifying the CSS page that is already included in the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

The login.jsp can be found in following jar.
/repository/components/plugins/org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.0.5.jar => /repository/components/plugins/login.jsp
and css => /repository/components/plugins

Comment: Yashita, since the /css folder in org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.0.3.jar does not contain login.css, must I add it?

Also, do I understand correctly that login_ajaxprocessor.jsp (the one I mention above) actually calls the login.jsp you are talking about?

Comment: CSS files you need to refer is global.css and main.css. Those two files can be found in org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.0.5.jar and org.wso2.esb.styles_4.6.0.jar